# How do I run a function after angularjs has re-rendered the template triggered by $scope.$watch?

Tags: angularjs

Here's an example:

```
<div my-directive my-attr="someNumericValueFromParentScopeVariable">
  <div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item.id}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

angular.directive( "myDirective", function(){
  return {
    scope : {
      myAttr : "="
    },
    controller : function($scope){
      $scope.$watch( "myAttr", function( newValue, oldValue, scope ) {
        var newItems = []; // contruct new array with n-size
        scope.items = newItems;
        // After this, the template will be rerendered. 
        // I want to recompute the new width of the div container and store it in the scope.
      }
    }
  };
});
```

If `my-attr` points to a scope variable and gets modified, the `scope.items` will be replaced and the `<div ng-repeat="item in items">` will be re-rendered. How do I compute the new width of the element `<div class="container">` after `<div ng-repeat="item in items">` has rendered its elements? I need to perform this computation after `$scope.$watch` has made its changes to the model and after the template has re-rendered due to changes in the model.

And is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function after the list has rendered by using the $timeout service:

```
$scope.$watchCollection( 'things', function(){
    $timeout( function(){
        // calculate width here
    });
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/59VLh/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Works great. But wouldn't this cause a race condition? I assume that the function passed to $timeout will be called asynchronously and it's possible that it will be called before even the rendering of template completes. Just my hunch, please correct me if I'm wrong.